# MakeSignature.SignDetached() closes all streams - Create signed PDF in memorystream

Tags: vb.net, pdf, itext, digital-signature

I have developed a function to sign a PDF created in memorystream and write it to a PDF. Now I'm looking to expand the function and instead of creating a PDF that is signed physically, I want to create the signed PDF in memory, so I can attach it to an email.

This is what I have:

```
    Using myPdfReader As New PdfReader(sourcePDFStream)
        Using myFileStream As New MemoryStream()
            Using myPdfStamper As PdfStamper = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(myPdfReader, myFileStream, "0"c)

                Dim myPdfSignatureAppearance As PdfSignatureAppearance = myPdfStamper.SignatureAppearance
                myPdfSignatureAppearance.SetVisibleSignature(New iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(100, 100, 250, 150), myPdfReader.NumberOfPages, "Digital Signature")

                Dim myExternalSignature As IExternalSignature = New PrivateKeySignature(pk, "SHA-256")
                MakeSignature.SignDetached(myPdfSignatureAppearance, myExternalSignature, chain, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, 0, CryptoStandard.CMS)

                clsMail.SendHTMLMailPackStream("niels@email.be", "EFFFFactuurFEB", "NL", "docname", myVars, myFileStream)
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
```

The problem I'm facing is that when I'm calling my 'SendHTMLMailPackStream' method, 'myfilestream' is already closed.

Does anyone knows an answer to this?

**EDIT:**

I found that everytime the MakeSignature.SignDetached() method is hit, it closes all my streams. But I have no idea how to cancel that..

Comment: As `myPdfStamper.Writer.CloseStream = false;` doesn't work, I deleted my answer. Maybe this is an issue that should be looked at by iText support. Do you have a support contract?

Comment: @BrunoLowagie No i don't.

Answer (score 0):

I checked the writer class that is at play when you create signatures. This class is called `PdfSignatureAppearance`. Its `Close()` method indeed doesn't allow you to keep the original stream open. There's probably a reason for that. You don't want to jeopardize your signed PDF by adding extra bytes.

Looking at your code, I don't understand why it's necessary to keep that `MemoryStream` open.

Have you written the `SendHTMLMailPackStream` method yourself? I don't know what the parameters are supposed to be, but it's very awkward that it would accept a `MemoryStream` that already contains a full PDF (and nothing but a full PDF). One would expect that it either expects a `byte[]` that can be added as Multi-Part data, or a `MemoryStream` to which a mail message and Multi-Part data is written.

I don't see any use case where you'd pass a `MemoryStream` containing a PDF. Which bytes would you add after the `%%EOF` of that PDF?

Are you sure you're doing it right? By the way: Olivier mailed me, and I proposed that he gets in touch with iText Software in case the problem remains unresolved.

Comment: the only this the stream will be used for is creating an attachment to an email:

Dim att As New Attachment(stream, "filename.pdf")

Comment: I'm not a .NET developer, but if .NET is similar to Java (which it is), I assume that `stream` should be an `InputStream`, not an `OutputStream`. Why don't you create an `InputStream` using the `byte[]` stored in the `MemoryStream`?

Comment: As far as I know, I need to hit the MakeSignature.SignDetached() method first, otherwise it doens't matter what's in the stream/byte[], the PDF won't be signed. The purpose is to have an PDF that is signed but not saved on disk, and send it immediately via mail.

Comment: Yes, `SignDetached()` needs to be called. This will result in a `byte[]` containing all the bytes of a properly signed PDF. This `byte[]` isn't stored on disk. It is kept in a `MemoryStream`. This `MemoryStream` is closed because we don't want anyone to accidentally add bytes to a complete PDF. The `byte[]` starts with the bytes `%PDF-` and ends with `%%EOF`. Obviously, you can take that `byte[]` and embed it into a mail, but it doesn't make sense to add bytes after the `%%EOF` when the `byte[]` starts with `%PDF`. I count on your common sense to understand this.

Comment: I found the solution. Problem was I didn't know you could create an byte[] from an closed MemoryStream.. It's my first time working with memorystreams. Thank you for you answers and time !

Comment: OK. That's great news :D

Answer (score 0):

I needed to create an Byte[] from the closed MemoryStream.

With that Byte[] I was able to create an new MemoryStream to create the signed PDF:

```
Dim myExternalSignature As IExternalSignature = New PrivateKeySignature(pk, "SHA-256")
MakeSignature.SignDetached(myPdfSignatureAppearance, myExternalSignature, chain, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, 0, CryptoStandard.CMS)

byteArray = myFileStream.ToArray()
```

Outside using:

```
Dim EndFileStream As New MemoryStream(byteArray)
clsMail.SendHTMLMailPackStream("niels@email.be", "EFFFFactuurFEB", "NL", "docname", myVars, EndFileStream)
```